# How to fix Unhandled exception thrown

Tags: c++, visual-c++

[image]

[image]

how to fix it,When I write the main function, and call to the set method, show me Unhandled exception. and show me the variable unable to read memory.

Comment: For future reference, please post code as text, not images.

Comment: Note also that you are indexing off the end of the array.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
shipContainer* shipContainer1[6];
```

That's not an array of `shipContainer` objects. It's an array of 6 **pointers** to `shipContainer` objects, which are actually stored somewhere else in memory.

But then the array is left uninitialized and the individual entries are not pointing anywhere. So when you try working with them, it crashes or exhibits some other undefined behavior.

If you wanted an array of 6 `shipContainer` objects instead, right there on the stack, do something like this:

```cpp
shipContainer shipContainer1[6];
shipContainer1[0].setContainerID(100);
```

I.e. 1) no asterisk on the first line, and 2) `.` instead of `->` on the subsequent ones.

---

Alternatively, if you want an array of pointers, you will need to initialize it to point to some valid constructed objects first, e.g.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    shipContainer1[i] = new shipContainer();
```

Note that the objects should then be also destructed somewhere later with a `delete` statement. Or just use a smart pointer. Or a full-fledged STL structure like `std::vector<>`. There is no need to handle all this by hand in C++.

Comment: is it possible to use pointer,if i still want to use with pointer, how to fix?Thanks

Comment: @JasonShen, you would need to initialize each member of the array with new. This is generally not recommended in modern c++

Comment: Edited to add the solution with pointers, but yes, it's discouraged to do it like that, too much hassle and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer states, each element of the array is a pointer, which needs to be initialized. Since you asked, I'll show how to initialize each member, however, I will preface by stating that this is not recommended in modern c++.

```
shipContainer* shipContainer1[6];
for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < 6; ++idx) 
    shipContainer1[idx] = new shipContainer;

shipContainer1[0]->setContainerID(100);
```

When done with the container, don't forget to delete.

```
for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < 6; ++idx) 
    delete shipContainer1[idx];
```